# Oreilly Multipart parser and dynamically created rows (through jquery)

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, multipartform-data

I have 2 jsp's:
createEdit.jsp and save.jsp

Inside createEdit.jsp I have a an html code inside a form and since it includes file upload, I am using encoding type "multipart/form-data". Inside the form I have a table. The requirement is to save the data from the table to the database. I can add row to the table dynamically through Jquery or Javascript.

This is my sample form having table:

```
<form  action="save.jsp" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="frm">
<table id="tblRating">
<tr><td><input id="e1">Element1</input><input id="e2"></input><td><tr>
</table>
</form>
```

The javascript code am using for adding rows dynamically to the exisitng table:

```
function generateRow(){
        console.log("Generate the row");
        var table = document.getElementById('tblRating');

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
            console.log(newcell.childNodes);
            switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                case "text":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                        break;
                case "checkbox":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                        break;
                case "select":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 'null';
                        break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Inside save.jsp I have a scriplet code (the code is quite old so it has scriplet).
It parses the request using Oreilly Multipart parser and fetches input element one by one.

Sample code for my save.jsp:

```
MultipartParser parser = new MultipartParser(request, 2 * 1024 * 1024);
String e1Value = ((ParamPart) parser.readNextPart()).getStringValue()); //reads the input elements only
String e2Value = ((ParamPart) parser.readNextPart()).getStringValue());
```

The issue is when I tried to read the elements through the parser, its able to get the existing rows on the form. But the parser doesn't take up the rows created through javascript.
I have tried printing the form on submit. It has the dynamically created rows. But when I tried to get the data from the parser it doesn't provide the rows created through javascript.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I am able to get through it.
The issue was not related to the multipart parser. It was the structure of the JSP that was crating an issue. Because of the existing structure the jsp form was not able to take up the Dynamically created elements.

Earlier the jsp structure was like this:

```
<table align=center border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=75%>
<form  onSubmit="return validate()" action=".." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="frmEntry">
<tr><td>........</td></tr>
</form>
</table>
```

The above structure was creating problem. So I just took the table inside of the form.

```
<form  onSubmit="return validate()" action=".." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="frmEntry">
<table align=center border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=75%>
<tr><td>........</td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

And it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd make sure each input has a unique name="..." attribute by appending the row number and column number to the name (e.g. myInput_2_3 would be the input in row 2, column 3).  You can use setAttribute('name', ...) on your newcell to set the input's name.